# Apache Felix Bundle Heap Memory Usage Monitoring

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

Is there a nice tool to monitor how much heap memory each of the OSGI bundles take over time ?

Thanks,
Retep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not generally possible to identify the amount of memory used by an individual bundle; only the amount of memory used by the whole application.

For example: suppose bundle A calls a method provided by bundle B, and the method in bundle B creates an object. Who is responsible for the memory consumed by that object? Bundle B created it directly, but it would not have done so if bundle A hadn't asked it to. So we cannot really assign that memory consumption to either A *or* B.

For monitoring memory consumption of the whole application I recommend [YourKit](http://yourkit.com/) and/or [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes currently I am using YourKit for the heap map analysis. Currently, I have added custom reporting to some bundles to check their usage statistics to have a profe of what's going on.